# How to quit Pycharm 'run file in console'

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to know how can I quit the *run file in console* mode because I can't run my code again.

[image]

Comment: Push the red square button on the left side.

Comment: I pushed,but when I run file again I can see it again (lol)

Comment: and what is that about lower right corner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is still running for some reason.  Is it at the `input()` prompt? Is so click by the prompt and enter what is needed.  Or, you can stop the program like:

[image]

Comment: and what is that about lower right corner? that "variables are not avaliable"?

Comment: @user9168666, that is the debugger pane.  Run in debugger mode to see variables.